# What is the login password to unlock Keyring Authorization in 20.04?

Tags: login, 20.04, password, unlock

At boot up, I get a pop up message stating, *Authentication Required, The login keyring did not get unlocked when you logged into your computer.*
Below this message there is a an area for the authorized password. I want to resolve this issue. Here is some general information that may be of importance: I have opted to have automatic login in settings. This is a relatively recent installation of Focal Fossa. I have created both administrator and user accounts.

Comment: Unless you gave keyring a separate password, then your password will unlock it.  Keyring is usually unlocked when you login, but you went with automatic so keyring is not getting unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you crip659 for the prompt. I returned to the Users configuration to check on the status of automatic login. (I had not opted in for it...I am often wrong...) I was asked to supply password twice, once for the "Authentication Required" message and the other for the user account. This seems to have resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04
I have had the same problem. Rather than fixing my user id I created a new user and set it up without automatic login.

Settings > Users > Unlock > Add User... > [Set Type to Administrator, Add Password Now] > [Be sure Automatic Login stays OFF] > exit Settings.

When you login as the new user you can Remove the old user, be sure to save files if offered. The downside to creating a new user is that you may lose some files and you will have to reinstall programs.